# asp.net active directory intranet

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have an intranet that gets the current logged in user through active directory.  When a user is locked out they get a windows prompt to enter their username and password.    Is there a way for me to catch this and redirect them to a page where they are asked to enter their credentials again or tell them that their account might be locked out and to contact the help desk?

Answer (score 0):

On your application once you grab the user that is logged in do the IsAccountLocked method below

```
public bool IsAccountLocked(string sUserName)
{
    UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = GetUser(sUserName);
    return oUserPrincipal.IsAccountLockedOut();
}

public UserPrincipal GetUser(string sUserName)
{
    PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext();

    UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, sUserName);
    return oUserPrincipal;
}

public PrincipalContext GetPrincipalContext()
{
    PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sDomain, sDefaultOU, ContextOptions.SimpleBind, sServiceUser, sServicePassword);
    return oPrincipalContext;
}
```

This is using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement for using only System.DirectoryServices you can do this

```
public bool IsAccountLocked(DirectoryEntry oDE)
{
    return Convert.ToBoolean(oDE.InvokeGet("IsAccountLocked"));
}
public DirectoryEntry GetUser(string sUserName)
{
    //Create an Instance of the DirectoryEntry
    oDE = GetDirectoryObject();

    //Create Instance fo the Direcory Searcher
    oDS = new DirectorySearcher();

    oDS.SearchRoot = oDE;
    //Set the Search Filter
    oDS.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + sUserName + "))";
    oDS.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    oDS.PageSize = 10000;

    //Find the First Instance
    SearchResult oResults = oDS.FindOne();

    //If found then Return Directory Object, otherwise return Null
    if (oResults != null)
    {
        oDE = new DirectoryEntry(oResults.Path, sADUser, sADPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        return oDE;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
private DirectoryEntry GetDirectoryObject()
    {
        oDE = new DirectoryEntry(sADPath, sADUser, sADPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        return oDE;
    }
```

for a full implementation you can go to 
http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/
or
http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/active-directory-objects-and-c/